# APEX 5.1: Automatic Copy of an app in Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, backup

Right now I have an "Production App" that changes everyday. Every Friday I go to `Tasks > Copy` this application

[Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm5gf.png)

And send that copy to another ID App, in order to have (for example) "Production App 2" as a backup (I have the DB backup in another server)

Is there any way to make that "backup" automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about exporting your applications regularly (e.g. on a daily basis)? You'd use [APEXExport](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEADM/managing-existing-workspaces.htm#AEADM-GUID-FC2A4006-96F0-45F0-B160-9964AB408688).

As it is invoked from the operating system command prompt, you can create a batch script (.bat on MS Windows) and schedule it (using Task Scheduler on MS Windows) to run at any time you want, e.g. 02:00 (2 hours past midnight)).

That's what I do, works just fine.

Comment: I'm gonna try this, I didn't know that this feature was available. I started with APEX 20 as practice for a new job, but in the company they have (for my surprise) APEX 5, so the functions were slightly different. Thank you for your response

Comment: Do you know why I keep getting this error?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver
        at oracle.apex.APEXExport.main(APEXExport.java:845)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        etc....

Comment: Did you set CLASSPATH? Don't forget to add `.\;` to its beginning, so that it looks like e.g. `.\;D:\oracle11\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar`. Also, make sure you do have the OJDBCx.JAR file ("x" differs from version to version. When I was on Apex 4.2, it was ojdbc14.jar I had to use. On 21.1, it is ojdbc6.jar).

Comment: You were right! The CLASSPATH was wrong. Now It's working! :) Just another question, can you execute this command in another folder? Or just in Utilities? I'm looking to save this exports in another folder

Comment: My procedure is copying export files to another folder.

Comment: Ok, I'm moving that file in the same batch. Thank you so much for your help! Have a nice day.

Comment: You're welcome; best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Starting APEX 20.1, there is a feature that takes regular [backups automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmdb/managing-application-backups.html). There is also this recent [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/building-a-rest-api-to-deploy-apex-apps) that shows how to use ORDS to export/import apps.

Comment: Yes... in APEX 20 they have that function, but in APEX 5 is not available, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

SQLcl is also a possibility through command line: [see here](https://www.talkapex.com/2018/07/exporting-apex-application-in-sqlcl-with-build-status-override/)